# ListLinePlot trace looks fuzzy with too many data points

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, graphics

I'm plotting a list of data (v) where some of the points are very close together. No problem if AbsoluteThickness[x] is set to x=0.5, but the trace begins to look fuzzy if x>2.5. This is mainly an issue at the beginning of each stair step, where there are a ton of data points. Is there anything I can do to fix this?

```
Voltage[x_] :=
 ListLinePlot[
  v,
  PlotStyle -> {Red, AbsoluteThickness[x]},
  PlotRange -> Automatic,
  ImageSize -> 600,
  LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 20, FontFamily -> "Helvetica", Black, 
    Bold},
  Frame -> {True, True, False, False},
  FrameLabel -> {{"Potential (V)", ""}, {"Time (h)", "" }}
  ]

Voltage[0.5]
Voltage[2.5]
Voltage[5]
```

[image]

And no, I cannot weed out data points so my graph looks better.

Thanks for taking the time to read this.

Comment: Can you provide some datapoints, at least around the beginning of the step?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/19keBRRHcJTHJ1dxI2fjYBM8V4A3qyaNpY3rD5yaMipE/edit?usp=sharing

This is the full list.

Comment: Adding `InterpolationOrder -> 0` as an option to `Plot` cleans it up a bit.  Is that good enough?

Comment: @march that is perfect! Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding InterpolationOrder -> 0 prevents this issue.

```
Voltage[x_] :=
 ListLinePlot[
  v,
  PlotStyle -> {Red, AbsoluteThickness[x]},
  PlotRange -> Automatic,
  ImageSize -> 600,
  LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 20, FontFamily -> "Helvetica", Black, 
    Bold},
  Frame -> {True, True, False, False},
  FrameLabel -> {{"Potential (V)", ""}, {"Time (h)", ""}},
  InterpolationOrder -> 0
  ]
```

[image]